# jQuery Mobile Phonegap Cordova Events not working and Firing

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

We have to build a mobile application using HTML5, to be worked on Android and IOS.
We started by using jQuery Mobile Framework to manage the pages and actions.Every thing is fine. The problem is when we use the Apache Cordova API, to get some info from the device like the uuid, and manage an Exit Application Button, nothing working!...
We use the Cordova Script which  get from this [Google Link](https://code.google.com/p/js-addin/issues/attachmentText?id=29&aid=290000000&name=cordova-2.5.0.js&token=0Y9Obv319QqouAEi8l1bslaDZQo%3A1396628304815).
We put the line below into the config.xml file before building the app pn phonegap:

```
<plugin name="Notification" value="org.apache.cordova.notification.Notification" />
```

We use the official documentation presented From Cordova Phonegap [Site](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html) , which is below:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Notification Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for Cordova to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Cordova is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Empty
    }

    // alert dialog dismissed
    function alertDismissed() {
        // do something
    }

    // Show a custom alertDismissed
    //
    function showAlert() {
        navigator.notification.alert(
            'You are the winner!',  // message
            alertDismissed,         // callback
            'Game Over',            // title
            'Done'                  // buttonName
        );
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><a href="#" onclick="showAlert(); return false;">Show Alert</a></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

But any thing not happened after building the sources to the Android Platform. No Events fired or anything related to phonegap!

We have searching many results and suggestions to resolve that but without any results!

The applications has been tested on Android 4.3.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using cordova 2.9.0 and upper cans resolve this issues.

theses lines are needed to put in the config.xml file:

```
<feature name="Device">
<param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.device.Device" />  // android
<param name="ios-package" value="CDVDevice" /> IOS
</feature>
<!-- -->
<plugins>
<plugin name="App" value="org.apache.cordova.App" />
<plugin name="Device" value="org.apache.cordova.Device" />
<plugin name="Device" value="CDVDevice" />
</plugins>
<!-- phonegap plugins -->
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" version="0.2.8" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a very old version of cordova (2.5), the latest version is 3.5 and here is the proper location for documentation and download: http://cordova.apache.org/

Try putting a console.log or alert inside onDeviceReady function to make sure cordova is initialised properly, but I think your problem is with the cordova project setup. Try creating a fresh project using 3.5 with command line as explained in documentation first.

Comment: Where can we find the latest cordova script from the link below http://cordova.apache.org/#download?

Comment: Please read the documentation, there is a step by step setup guide for each platform. You can also see phonegap build documentation, if you are planning to use pg build (I never used it).

Comment: Why this code is not working even with the old version!

Comment: I understand you, Thanks, but what's exactly needed is the new JS File to test the result!

Comment: no, because, as I said, your code looks ok to me, I am guessing your project configuration is the problem, but that's just my guess.

Comment: An Alert Error has been occurred!  [error] initializing cordova class not found!

Comment: Search the error in SO, you've got several answers. It's still related to your cordova project setup I think.

Comment: There was a problem with the old version of Cordova API! version 2.9.1 is working, version 3.5.0 needs some plugins. Also same requirements were needed to be added to config.xml file, plugins and performances.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the device plugin from the command line:

```
phonegap plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
```

This has worked for me in the past. The command is the same for Windows, Linux and Mac. Then put something into your deviceready event to ensure that it's being fired.

Comment: Well Thank you for your response. The onDeviceReady function is called now. The problem is with device info. We test it on desktop browser and android mobile, and all parameters (device name, uuid, cordova) return null!

Comment: We just added <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" /> in the config.xml file, although this action , there is no parameters to display!

Comment: We need the device.uuid value and this return nul when using cordova 2.9.1!