# attr not working in cordova for image from other domain

Tags: jquery, cordova

I am trying to show image on hybrid app dynamically. I mean images are located on the server and i am showing them on cordova app.

i have added cordova and jquery in the head section.
Here is the code.

```
var pics = "http://www.test.com/img/53_20160713104002.png";

        document["profile-pic"].src = pics;
        $("#profile-pic").attr("src", pics);
```

Here is the html code.

```
<a href="profile.html" data-original-title="" title="">
     <img width="35" height="30" id="profile-pic" class="profile img-circle" name="profile-pic" /></a>
```

Please advise what am i doing wrong.

**Edit**: It seems like issue is due to cross domain. I have white listed the domain in config file.

Comment: It seems to work: https://jsfiddle.net/8jwqL6s4/

Comment: it is working fine in browser not in mobile as app or simulator.

Comment: @CalculatingMachine Can you check if jQuery is working on the mobile? What version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Feels like jQuery isn't working in the Cordova application. Try using:

```js
var pics = "http://www.test.com/img/53_20160713104002.png";

document["profile-pic"].src = pics;
document.getElementById("profile-pic").setAttribute("src", pics);
```

If the above code works, then you have to find out why jQuery isn't working in Cordova.

> Some pointers for the next issue:
>
> - [Jquery not working with phoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128270/jquery-not-working-with-phonegap)
> - [Phone Gap Jquery not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20413505/phone-gap-jquery-not-working)
> - [PhoneGap (Cordova.js) and JQuery.Ajax not working together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469959/phonegap-cordova-js-and-jquery-ajax-not-working-together)
> - [jQuery Mobile Phonegap Cordova Events not working and Firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25579212/jquery-mobile-phonegap-cordova-events-not-working-and-firing)
> - [Javascript and JQuery not working on Phonegap](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/javascript-and-jquery-not-working-on-phonegap)

Comment: thnks for your answer. let me try.

Comment: @CalculatingMachine Is there any way for you to debug the app? Like, ... I am not sure. Check if jQuery is loading? The image is loaded before the script is executed?

Comment: let me try. I will update you. At the moment i am also debugging it. concern is it is woking fine in browser.

Comment: @CalculatingMachine I know... You should understand that the way browser interprets and the way Cordova does, both are very different.